# How to adjust the price when I remove an item in my DataGridView (Does not connect with any database) Vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to adjust the subtotal when i remove the item in my data grid view (does not connect any data base.

`

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
                Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Add("H.Burger", "10.90")
                Subtotal = Subtotal + "RM10.9"
                Me.Label13.Text = Subtotal.ToString()
            End Sub
            Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
                Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Add("S.Carborana", "12.90")
                Subtotal = Subtotal + 12.9
                Me.Label13.Text = Subtotal.ToString()
            End Sub
            Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
                Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Add("N.Lemak", "5.90")
                Subtotal = Subtotal + 5.9
                Me.Label13.Text = Subtotal.ToString()
            End Sub
            Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
                Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Add("CurryMee", "7.90")
                Subtotal = Subtotal + 7.9
                Me.Label13.Text = Subtotal.ToString()
            End Sub
            Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
                Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Add("CCRice", "8.90")
                Subtotal = Subtotal + 8.9
                Me.Label13.Text = Subtotal.ToString()
            End Sub
```

Comment: Some additional information would be useful in order to help you. Which events are you handling? How are you deleting the rows from the grid? If you give us these information we can find a smooth solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like below code

```
Private Sub AdjustPrice()
        Dim price As Decimal = 0
        For x = 0 To Datagridview1.Rows.Count - 1
            If Not IsDBNull(Datagridview1.Rows(x).Cells([your cell goes here]).Value) Then price = price + Datagridview1.Rows(x).Cells([your cell goes here]).Value
        Next
        lblPrice.Text = FormatCurrency(sum.ToString())
    End Sub
```

set the the `AdjustPrice` on form load or where you want to start the action.

from above code, you can display your Price on Lable or Textbox

Try and let me know